# Content Provider is part of my application?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-contentprovider

I need to create 3 things:

- Content Provider
- Service
- Application

I'm wondering if these all three will be in one single project, or they will be three different projects?

Also how can I limit my Content Provider to my services and my applications?

Regards,
Pentium10

Comment: There are no restrictions: everything can go in a single Android project. You define in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file what activities, services and content providers are contained in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would be a single project. They are [application framework objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and not as heavyweight as you might currently believe.

As far as permissions, check the [security guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#manifest)

Answer (score -1):

To get more detailled answers maybe you could specify what type of "Content Provider", "Service" and "Application" you 'need' to create - and why..? ..a pay-for-content app..? ..a music-download portal..?

Comment: oops - I think I didn't quite get the question. Sorry, if my 'answer' missed the point..